# Using CATransformLayer warning: changing property opaque in transform-only layer, will have no effect

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, subclass, catransformlayer

I created a "`TransformView`" subclassing `UIView` in order to support a double-sided view which I am using in a flip animation. This has been suggested in other posts, eg:

[How to rotate a flat object around its center in perspective view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423892/how-to-rotate-a-flat-object-around-its-center-in-perspective-view/9425938#9425938)

```
@interface TransformView : UIView
@end

@implementation TransformView
+ (Class)layerClass {
  return [CATransformLayer class];
}
@end
```

It all works fine, but I get a warning every time I create a TransformView object using:

```
TransformView *newTransformView=[[TransformView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

The warning says:

> - changing property opaque in
>   transform-only layer, will have no effect

I guess the `UIView` class is initialising the opaque property which is usually fine for a `CALayer` but not a `CATransformLayer`.

Is the subclassing code quite dodgy? If so, how else can you create a 2-sided view for flip animations?

Any ideas for how to stop the warning?

I have a suspicion that creating a `TransformView` from a nib file rather than `initWithFrame` avoids the warning, but is seem cludgy to have to do this just to avoid the warning.

Comment: Filed as [rdar://23069576](https://openradar.appspot.com/23069576)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your can avoid the warning by adding this extension somewhere in your code:

```
@implementation CATransformLayer (MyExtension)
-(void)setOpaque:(BOOL)opaque
{
    return;
}
@end
```

Of course this will also stop the warning for your own mistaken attempts to set the opaque property of a CATransformLayer.